# Best way to write to Kafka from web site?

Tags: apache-kafka

I mean I know how to get data into kafka either by some file agent or programmatically using any of the clients, but speaking from architectural point of view...

It can't just be collecting HTTP logs.

I'm assuming when someone clicks a link or does something of interest, we can use some kind of ajax/javascript call to make a call to some microservice to capture the extra info that we want? But that's not always "reliable" per say, but do we care?

Or while the given "action" posts back to the server we simultaneously write to Kafka and perform the other action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear from your question if you are trying to collect all the clickstream logs from a set of web servers, or if you are trying to selective publish some data to Kafka from your web app, so I will answer both.

The easiest way to collect every web click is to configure your web servers to use Syslog ( see http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/10/12/httpd-syslog.html ) and configure your Syslog server to send data to Kafka (see https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-kafka.html). Alternatively there are some more advanced features available in this Kafka Connector for Syslog-NG (see https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-syslog). You can also write httpd logs to a file and use a Kafka File Connector to publish to Kafka (see https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html)

If you just want to enable your apps to send certain log data to Kafka directly you can use the Kafka REST Proxy and publish using a simple HTTP POST from either your client JavaScript or your server side logic (see https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html)

Comment: I already mentioned those methods file agent or using using some kafka client.  I guess it comes down to what we can put in the URI/Path...

Comment: There are all kinds of other Kafka connectors that can capture everything up to the entire IP packet stream

Comment: I know.... Just thinking in my head or trying to find a clearer way to explain without giving away what Im trying to do....

Comment: There are tools to do all kinds of packet capture and CyberSecurity style monitoring with Kafka. Check out OpenSOC and Apache Metron https://github.com/apache/metron/blob/master/metron-platform/metron-pcap-backend/README.md

Comment: Cool. But its more of say I have a bunch of events already stored in kafka that belong to a "conversation" that lead the user to an html form. The form is POST to rdbms. I guess I can just associate by some unique Id at later time and consolidate everything together...

Comment: Kafka Streams can join clickstream data with other user data such as user id, IP address, location, etc to make an enriched data stream for real-time analytics. See KSQL examples https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/0.1.x/docs/quickstart/README.md

Comment: Ok now we getting somewhere. Going through that example where does the data for the user come from? Obviously userid, registertime and gender are not something that are in http logs...

Comment: It comes from a database who’s change log gets published to another Kafka topic that the KSQL statements does a join on with the page view topic

Comment: Ah lol I was afraid you would say that lol Cause thats where it gets tricky to sync db table to kafka. I know there's plenty of ways... I just dont like any of them lol But I get it now.

Comment: Yeah exactly. The jdbc connector realies on the two later if i recall... CDC depends if its an "enterprise" feature of the db and custom code gets tricky... Ok cool thanks for the info...

Comment: Check out Debezium for Open Source CDC into Kafka